# Bootstrap 4 - Responsive horizontal navs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running into a problem with Bootstrap 4 navs where nav links overhang if their container is too small in width. This is very often the case for mobile devices.

Here is an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLKGrx

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3 columnbg">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">LongTabName</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">LongTabName</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">LongTabName</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">LongTabName</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">LongTabName</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to achieve something that is suitable for smaller displays. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`col-6` is only half width on the smallest screens, so it doesn't accurately emulate a mobile screen width. When the nav's content is too long for mobile widths, you can use one of the other utility classes to show less content (abbr. labels or just icons) in the nav.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><span class="hidden-xs-down">LongTabName</span><span class="hidden-sm-up">TN</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="hidden-xs-down">LongTabName</span><span class="hidden-sm-up">TN</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="hidden-xs-down">LongTabName</span><span class="hidden-sm-up">TN</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="hidden-xs-down">LongTabName</span><span class="hidden-sm-up">TN</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="hidden-xs-down">LongTabName</span><span class="hidden-sm-up">TN</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/WXqhlCDp9o

Comment: A reasonable solution, I didn't think of this. I ended up with two additional classes `nav-fill nav-pills-responsive` and I defined the latter with `flex-wrap: wrap;` which works nicely although not the prettiest. A combination of the two would be the best in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is built for mobile-first. The only reason you're running into this problem is because you aren't fully implementing the [`navbar`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#content):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I wasn't wanting a `navbar` but more so a sub navigator. I use the card component and my navigator is inside of `.card-header`. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick in css that could help you specify for an element to resize depending by the screen width.height:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
     //change width here
  }
}
```

As you can see, when the screen's width gets lower than 600px (for mobile should be smaller), the `@media` css will overwrite ;)

Comment: The issue isn't with `.row`. I only set a column there so you can see the overhang that occurs with the nav. It doesn't matter what width a row has, if the nav doesn't fit horizontally then it will overhang.

Comment: Than change the element, it doesn't really have to be `.row`, mathc it with the wrong element there